# Removing Comma from .csv column field and import to db

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2

The below class will import the .csv into database table.it is working fine.
But when, it come across the numeric values like this 2,345. It result in error.

In my .csv files there are 3 columns like this:

Datatypes for these columns in db2 table "COMPUTER" is  COL_A(VArchar 50), COL_B(Double), COL_C(Varchar 50)

COL_A                          |           COL_B                             |     COL_C

---

KKGG56                          |       7,567                                |     JUNE2013

GGHHK2                          |       259,024                              |     MAY 2012

So, how to remove the these comma from the particular column while importing into the db table and where to place the code in my program?  Please help.

```
public class CSVLoader {

private static final 
    String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO OPM.${table}
         (${keys})      VALUES(${values})";

private static final String TABLE_REGEX = "\\$\\{table\\}";

private static final String KEYS_REGEX = "\\$\\{keys\\}";

private static final String VALUES_REGEX = "\\$\\{values\\}";

private Connection connection;

private char seprator;

public CSVLoader(Connection connection) {

    this.connection = connection;

    //Set default separator

    this.seprator = ',';
}

      public void loadCSV(String csvFile, String tableName) throws Exception {

    CSVReader csvReader = null;

    if(null == this.connection) {

        throw new Exception("Not a valid connection.");
    }

    try {

        csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile), this.seprator);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        throw new Exception("Error occured while executing file. "

                   + e.getMessage());

              }

        String[] headerRow = csvReader.readNext();

    if (null == headerRow) {

        throw new FileNotFoundException(


                        "No columns defined in given CSV file." +

                         "Please check the CSV file format.");
    }

    String questionmarks = StringUtils.repeat("?,", headerRow.length);

    questionmarks = (String) questionmarks.subSequence(0, questionmarks

            .length() - 1);


    String query = SQL_INSERT.replaceFirst(TABLE_REGEX, tableName);

    query = query
            .replaceFirst(KEYS_REGEX, StringUtils.join

             (headerRow,   ","));

    query = query.replaceFirst(VALUES_REGEX, questionmarks);

            System.out.println("Query: " + query);

    String[] nextLine;

    Connection con = null;

    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    try {
        con = this.connection;

        con.setAutoCommit(false);

        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

                       final int batchSize = 1000;

                     int count = 0;

        Date date = null;

        while ((nextLine = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {

            System.out.println( "inside while" );

            if (null != nextLine) {

                int index = 1;

                for (String string : nextLine) {

                    date = DateUtil.convertToDate(string);

        if (null != date) {

                    ps.setDate(index++, new java.sql.Date(date

                    .getTime()));

                     } else {

                  ps.setString(index++, string);

    System.out.println( "string" +string);

                    }

                }

                ps.addBatch();

            }

            if (++count % batchSize == 0) {

                ps.executeBatch();

            }

                     }


        ps.executeBatch(); // insert remaining records

        con.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        con.rollback();

        e.printStackTrace();

        throw new Exception(

        "Error occured while loading data 

                from file                to                      database."

               + e.getMessage());

    } finally {

             if (null != ps)


            ps.close();

        if (null != con)

            con.close();

            System.out.println("csvReader will be closed");

        csvReader.close();

    }

}

public char getSeprator() {

    return seprator;

}

public void setSeprator(char seprator) {

    this.seprator = seprator;

}


         }
```

Comment: I don't understand your code...do you know **in advance** file format, table name and column names or this is generic code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:
You have to parse your CSV text using `Double.parseDouble("2,345".replaceAll(",",""))` but you have to call `ps.setDouble()` to store a double in database, not `ps.setString()`!

```
for (String string : nextLine) {
  date = DateUtil.convertToDate(string);

  if (null != date) {
    ps.setDate(index++, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
  } 
  else {
     try {
       final double doubleValue = Double.parseDouble(string.replaceAll(",",""));

       ps.setDouble(index++, doubleValue);
     }
     catch(NumberFormatException e) {
       // For invalid double
       ps.setString(index++, string);
     }
  }
```

This code is not so robust, if you have a date or a number in 3rd column you will go into trouble! look at 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067934/parsing-csv-file-with-java/18068238#18068238  to use advance mapping solution you you know data structure in advance.

Comment: Hi Bellabax, I tried ur solution but it didnt help. It resulted in error. "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "KKGG56". Here i want to remove comma from the middle column. plz help in fixing these.

Comment: Edited my answer with right exception catched (NumberFormatException  instead of ParseException)

Comment: Hi Bellabax, I added as u said but no luck. it is not inserting . Please help .

Comment: Hi Bellabax, THANK U VERY MUCH. :-). The solution which u provided worked.It was my mistake I didnt included the braces properly.

Comment: Hi Bellabax, Can u please help me fixing "resultset Problem". Please, navigate to this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422348/comparing-two-resultset-of-two-different-tables. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is only one column with comma in it, extract the first N column values from the string(going in a forward direction). Then extract the last value(going in the reverse direction). Whatever remains is the middle column.

Comment: Can u please provide me the code for that and please let me know where i suppose to place that.